# document.getElementById--how does it work with onchange event?

Tags: javascript, html, css

My input has 2 functions:

```
`isAllowedSymbol` and `checkLength`.
```

`isAllowedSymbol` is working great, but  `checkLength` isn't. I need to make my length only 10 numbers long. What am I doing wrong? Where is my mistake? Please advise me on exactly how to do this.

```
type="text" maxlength="10" name="answer" id="t" onkeyup="isAllowedSymbol(this);" onchenge="checkLength(this);" placeholder="Enter data" >

function checkLength(this) {

  var element = document.getElementById('t');

  if(document.createEvent)
  {
      var e = document.createEvent('HTMLEvents');
      e.initEvent('change', false, true);
      element.dispatchEvent(e);
  }
}
```

Comment: Typo on the html attribute for onchange... `onchenge`

Comment: Why do you have to `checkLength` if the browser already enforces it using the `maxlength` you already applied?

Comment: It's also invalid to use `this` as the parameter name in the function as that is a reserved word and has special mechanisms setting its value depending on the context. The implementation of `checkLength()` appears to make no sense either, but maybe it's not just finished.

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 `maxlength` will automatically validate your input. But in case if you want to do some more validation try to use `onkeydown` than `onchange`.

**HTML:**

```
    <input type="text" maxlength="10" name="answer" id="t" onkeyup="isAllowedSymbol(this)" onkeydown="checkLength(this)" placeholder="Enter data">
```

**JavaScript:**

```
function checkLength(obj){
 //Your validation code goes here.
}
```

Hope this helps you.